# Masterpage Alternate CSS loading order

Tags: 2013, css, master-page

We have a custom Bootstrap-based master page for our sites. We have several different sites which each have their own design elements, colors, etc. Currently we have to make different copies of the master page to include the custom css for each site.

We could put the custom css into the page layouts, but that gets difficult to maintain and sometimes we have issues with loading order so we would prefer to keep the css in the masterpage.

I was hoping that we could use the `Site settings > Master page > Alternate CSS URL` to include the custom file on each site. Unfortunately that loads the css like so

1. Core-Themed
2. Theme15
3. Alternate CSS
4. Bootstrap

We are using cssregistration on our master page and can control the order of the css files we list on the masterpage, but I don't see a place to use **After=Bootstrap.css**.

Is there a way to control the load order of the Alternate CSS on the masterpage. It seems like an "alternate" should load at the end anyways to give it a chance to overwrite.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Move your PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead placeholder to the bottom of head tag in your custom master page.